# Shutdown not completing cleanly on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, shutdown, macbook

I recently did a clean install of Ubuntu 22.04 on my 2008 MacBook 4.1 and then installed the Unity desktop. (I actually like Unity and am prepared to take the performance hit compared to a lighter desktop.)

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64 
Host: MacBook4,1 1.0 
Kernel: 5.19.0-41-generic 
Uptime: 18 mins 
Packages: 2138 (dpkg), 10 (flatpak), 
Shell: bash 5.1.16 
Resolution: 1280x800 
DE: Unity 7.6.0 
WM: Compiz 
WM Theme: Yaru-dark 
Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: ubuntu-mono-dark [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo T8300 (2) @ 2.4 GHz 
GPU: Intel Mobile GM965/GL960 
Memory: 1579MiB / 3903MiB
```

Everything works great except that when I shut it down, the shutdown doesn't complete. This issue also happens with Gnome 3.

If I choose verbose shutdown so I can see what is going on, the process completes without error and the screen goes black but the fans remain running and the white light on the front illuminates if I close the lid. I have to then hard shutdown by holding the power button down for 5s.

Does anyone have any tips to force a complete shutdown on this hardware? Just in case its relevant, reboot works fine.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  Ubuntu Unity 22.04 was a *respin*, as it wasn't an official flavor until Ubuntu 22.10. You'd be on-topic here with 22.10 & 23.04, but you're not with 22.04 or earlier (nor Linux Mint)

Comment: Issue also happens on Gnome 3, post edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding acpi=force to the grub configuration.

1. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
2. Add acpi=force to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line e.g. `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"`
3. `sudo update-grub`

And now it shuts down cleanly!